# rails: devise validatable unit test always passes when it should fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, devise

I'm missing something here, but I can't seem to find the problem.  This test is really simple, and it should fail but it always passes.  It's creating a user with non matching passwords.

I have this in my user model.  So I know :validatable is set.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

When I test it manually using the console it works just fine. It won't let me save mis-matched passwords

Here is the unit test:

```
user = User.new_normal_user(
          :email                  => 'some@email.com', 
          :password               => 'some_password', 
          :password_confirmation  => 'some_other_password'
          )          

assert user.save
```

But for some strange reason when running the unit test it saves, when it shouldn't.  I'm stumped.  I can't figure this out.

Comment: I have resolved the issue.  I can't post my answer yet as I'm a new user.  I had overwritten the password_required? function.  Where it would only return false under certain conditions.  It would never return true.  So I just made it return true or false when it should and the unit test is working as expected and catching the passwords not matching issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.  I had overwritten the password_required? function.  Where it would only return false under certain conditions.  It would never return true.  So I just made it return true or false when it should and the unit test is working as expected and catching the passwords not matching issue.